# Sending push notification through Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am well aware of how the push notifications work on parse and how to implement it...But what i want to know is that can i change the behaviour of push notifications depending on whether the user is online or offline (not using app).....the beahaviour i am talking about is that i want to show push notifications to offline users only but for online users i dont want it to be shown rather i want to increment some variable (say notifications count). Is push notification the right thing for the behaviour i want or i should look for something else to increment notification counts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. But if the device is offline then you can't use push notifications from the web with something like parse.

Comment: What kind of notifications are you trying to send to offline users?

Comment: By offline i mean those who are connected to internet but not using the app....and i am talking about push notifications.... i have an app where user can create events in a group....so when an event is created i want to send push notifications to all the users but only those who are offline should see the push notification, for the online ones i want to increment a badge count variable only and dont show push notification in the tray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and declare your new broadcastreceiver to your manifest instead. You can then override the default behaviour of pushes you receive like checking if the user is online or offline.

There is a section in the Android Dev Guide "Receiving Pushes" for more info.

Comment: I got your point...but are you sure  that  it is possible to override default behaviour (which is a notification is shown in the tray) and do something else with the data instead?

Comment: Ok i just red the "Receiving Pushes" section which i didnt read carefully before....seems like it is possible to do something in background rather than showing push notification in the tray by overriding onPushReceive method in com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver .

Comment: but i would be thankful if you confirm it too..so that i should start working on it without any hesitation

Comment: I confirm that you can. In the end you are overriding the default behaviour of the existing broadcast receiver. It is entirely up to you what you do next depending on your use case. In my project for example, I modified the push message a bit to include a push type. Depending on the push type I can either start a service to do something in the background or display a notification.